# Multiple regex match in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
document.querySelectorAll("table[id^='Table']");
```

This code selects all tables with the id of `Table`. But i want to select tables with id of `Table2 OR Table7` (or any other numbers). How to do this with regex?

Edit: jQuery is not applicable in my case.

Comment: jquery is not applicable in my case

Comment: The code in the question should do this. Why don't you use that?

Comment: I want also add a number match and have no idea to do this with regex

Comment: Its working for me http://jsfiddle.net/qQ7VT/

Comment: Ah, so `Tablesomeletters` should not match, but `table6` (or any other number) should? @Adige72

Comment: @11684 Yes that's exactly what i want to do. I tried `table[id^='Table([0-9])` to match all numbers, even it's not my goal, but doesnt work either

Comment: I'm working on an answer right now.

Comment: How long can the number after `Table` be? One or more digits? (If it's one, I can simplify the regex from my answer.)

Comment: @11684 Yes it's one digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getTables(tableNumbers) { // Usage: getTables([2, 7]) will return the tables with the ID 'Table2' and 'Table7'. (You can add more numbers; [2,7,3,6])
    var allTables = document.querySelectorAll("table[id^='Table']");
    var tablesWeWant = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < allTables.length; i++) {
        if (allTables[i].id.match(/Table[0-9]/)) {
            tablesWeWant.push(allTables[i]);
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < tablesWeWant.length; i++) {
        if (!tableNumbers.contains(tablesWeWant[i].id.substr(id.length - 1))) {
            tableNumbers.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return tablesWeWant;
}
```

This should return all tables with an ID matching the regex `/Table[0-9]/` and ending with a digit contained in the variable `tableNumbders`.

DISCLAIMER: I'm not a regex expert.

**EDIT:**
After editing a few times the code above became a bit too long, so I rewrote it like this:

```
function getTables(tableNumbers) {
    var tablesWeWant = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tableNumbers.length; i++) {
        tablesWeWant.push(document.querySelector("#Table" + tableNumbers[i]));
    }
    return tablesWeWant;
}
```

The second approach works: http://jsfiddle.net/qQ7VT/1/

Comment: I just adjusted the regex. (I removed the `+` to match only one digit.) @Adige72

Comment: There's a problem. Even `tablesWeWant` is empty it selects all `Table*`

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. If `tablesWeWant` is empty, it didn't select any tables at all! Let me make an edit to make the code more clear. @Adige72

Comment: I've tried `var tablesWeWant = [2, 7];` to select tables with id of Table2 and Table7 but it selects all tables

Comment: Ah! No, that's not how the code is meant to work. The code will select all tables with an ID that match that regex, and put them in the variable `tablesWeWant`. I will make another edit. @Adige72

Comment: @Adige72 I think the code after my edit should do what you want.